# csv loader failed to load reason wrong number of values .Read 10,expected 8 ,read token [EOL] ,line 17

Tags: weka

I am trying to convert a CSV to ARFF using Weka's CSVLoader from the GUI. In the options I set the enclosure character for strings to be , . I get the following error:

weka.core.converters.csvloader failed to load

reason

wrong number of values .Read 10,expected 8 ,read token eol ,line 17

Here are lines 17

opensource:indicator-7fb1f287-3e7d-4069-8c41-ae7699055c81   sid:2405035 | "ET CNC Shadowserver Reported CnC Server Port 6667 Group 11" | rev:3590   IP Watchlist    SNORT Rule by Emergingthreats | alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> [217.146.93.144,217.146.93.146,217.188.63.252,217.195.122.2,217.208.43.77,220.99.77.147,222.73.84.17,222.122.47.78] 6667 (msg:"ET CNC Shadowserver Reported CnC Server Port 6667 Group 11"; flags:S; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/bin/view/Main/BotCC; reference:url,www.shadowserver.org; threshold: type limit, track by_src, seconds 360, count 1; classtype:trojan-activity; flowbits:set,ET.Evil; flowbits:set,ET.BotccIP; sid:2405035; rev:3590;) opensource:Observable-fe41db2c-da28-4e1e-96e1-95a06fa7b908  opensource:ttp-8becbdf1-c430-4fc9-a902-144841e375a6 rules.emergingthreats.net   NA

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to explain this with use of example.
if your csv file has header like:

```
id, body, class
1, 2, even
2, 6, even
3, 11, odd
```

then if there is some entry like

```
4,15, , odd
```

(notice 4 columns). Then there will be error message( Read 4, expected 3).
So check at line 17 you might have done same mistake. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to open CSV for WEKA in mac and after processing and saving the file in excel, this happened to me.
Trying with a text editor was the same.
The data contained values like "Don't know/Not Sure" The ' or / has caused the error in the file. After replacing the characters I could open the file.